# How to delete data row in Grid view in Asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to delete data in grid view using grid view RawDeleting event.
I am face this kind of Error:

> Error 1   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs' does not
>   contain a definition for 'RawIndex' and no extension method 'RawIndex'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\love\Desktop\Crime Management System\Crime
>   Management System\Admin\ManageLocation.aspx.cs

```
   protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
   {
       p.Sid = Convert.ToInt16(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RawIndex].Value);
       p.DeleteState(p);
       Response.Write("State Deleted");
       FillStates();
   }
```

method of Delete State:

```
    public void DeleteState(Property p)
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("DeleteState", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sid", p.Sid);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

    }
```

I have facing error in deleting event near RoaIndex, can you help me how to solve it?

Comment: The property name is [`RowIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewdeleteeventargs.rowindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and not `RawIndex`

Answer (score 0):

it's `RowIndex` not `RawIndex`,
change you code

```
p.Sid = Convert.ToInt16(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RawIndex].Value);
```

to

```
p.Sid = Convert.ToInt16(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
```